# perl ranking numbers with tie / draws

Tags: algorithm, perl, sorting, hash, integer

I have an array of integers,  but this is not the typical ranking of 1,2,3,4,5 etc.  If the integers have the same value, the rank is also the same value.  Example 1,2,2,4,5.  However we need to pad the ranks out accordingly. So skip rank 3 because there are two 2's.

1,2,3,3,5 instead of 1,2,3,3,4

The array of integers can be a few thousands,  so an efficient algorithm would be ideal.  Best if it can be written in perl as a function which can be given an input.

array of integers = 1000,2000,3000,3000,3500

would get the result = 1,2,3,3,5

another example

integers = 100,200,200,200,300,400,500,500,1000,2000

rank = 1,2,2,2,5,6,7,7,9,10

Comment: What is the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use hash to remember positions for repeating values in `@integers` array,

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @integers = sort {$a <=> $b} (100,200,200,200,300,400,500,500,1000,2000);

my %seen;
my @rank = map { $seen{$integers[$_]} //= $_+1 } 0 .. $#integers;

# same as
# my @rank = map { $seen{$integers[$_]} //= $_+1; $seen{$integers[$_]} } 0 .. $#integers;

use Data::Dumper; print Dumper \@rank;
```

output

```
$VAR1 = [
      1,
      2,
      2,
      2,
      5,
      6,
      7,
      7,
      9,
      10
    ];
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
use strict;

my @test = (100,200,200,200,300,400,500,500,1000,2000);
my @sorted = sort {$a <=> $b} @test;
my $rank = 1;
my @ranks;
foreach my $count (0..$#sorted) {
    $rank = $count + 1 if ($count > 0 && $sorted[$count] != $sorted[$count - 1]);
    push @ranks, $rank;
}

print join ",", @ranks;
```